# Problemas al subir mi programa de Laravel a Hostinger

Tags: laravel, hosting, host

este es mi sistema de carpetas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya viene por defecto en domains una carpeta con mi dominio que es larmor.com.mx y ahi esta la carpeta public_html y ahi guarde otra carpeta con todos mis archivos a excepcion de la carpeta public:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi index.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));


require __DIR__.'/larmor.com.mx/larmor/vendor/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/larmor.com.mx/larmor/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

(Quite los comentarios)

y este mi AppServiceProvider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public',function(){
      return'/larmor.com.mx/public_html';
    });
}
```

Ya intente de diferentes formas, comienzo con el directo en /domains/larmor.com.mx/... y ni asi funciona, por cierto, todos los cambios que haga en domains/larmor.com.mx, la carpeta que esta abajo de domains guarda esos cambios

La verdad no tengo mucha experiencia con hostinger y no se en que este mal, ya revise el log y los errores marcados son de hace dos dias atras por otros errores cometidos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya logre obtener resultados en el laravel.log, sin embargo no entiendo muy bien estos errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aun asi cuando pongo mi ip, me lanza un 403 Forbidden

Comment: en el index.php intenta hacer un `dd()` de tu variable `__DIR__` para ver que ruta es la 'base'

Comment: en que parte del index pongo mi `dd(__DIR__)`...y si es asi? o `dd($app)` ???

Comment: Tu dominio es el que presenta el problema, tu sitio es inalcanzable o no existe. Te sugiero revisar con tu proveedor para que te diga más al respecto

Comment: De alguna manera no soporta estar a ese nivel de las carpetas, cuando me pasaba eso lo que hacia era ponerlo al mismo nivel que mi carpeta donde esta mi index, (no es conveniente pero el servidor no me dejo de otra)

Answer (score 1):

He tenido el mismo problema con hostinger, pero combinando lo aprendido de varios tutoriales he podido solucionarlo.

En el archivo appServiceProvider debe quedar la función register así:

```
public function register()
{
  $this->app->bind('path.public',function(){
    return base_path().'/public_html';
  });
}
```

En cuanto al index.php de public, debe quedar así:

```
require __DIR__.'/../tucarpetalaravelsinpublic/vendor/autoload.php'

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../tucarpetalaravelsinpublic/bootstrap/app.php'
```

Luego, si no hiciste el composer dump-autoload antes de subir el proyecto, debes ir a bootstrap/cache y borrar config.php.

Tanto la carpeta laravel como la carpeta public_html deben quedar al mismo nivel, dentro de la carpeta tudominio.com.